# Загрузка изображения webview android

Tags: java, android, android-webview

я пытаюсь создать Android приложения для своего сайта которое, как и стандартный браузер могло бы загружать/скачивать изображения на устройство при нажатии кнопок на сайте.

Суть проблемы:

- На данный момент загрузить картинку можно чисто с устройства, мне нужно чтобы как и в браузере появлялся выбор между загрузкой с устройства и использованием камеры.
- При переадресации новая страница уже открывается не в моем приложении, а в браузере.

Вот код:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView mbrowser;
    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
    public ValueCallback<Uri[]> uploadMessage;
    public static final int REQUEST_SELECT_FILE = 100;
    private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_SELECT_FILE) {
                if (uploadMessage == null) return;
                uploadMessage.onReceiveValue(WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.parseResult(resultCode, intent));
                uploadMessage = null;
            }
        } else if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
            if (null == mUploadMessage) return;
            Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != MainActivity.RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUploadMessage = null;
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mbrowser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        mbrowser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mbrowser.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        mbrowser.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        mbrowser.loadUrl("http://tortillum.pythonanywhere.com/");
        mbrowser.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
                return true;
            }

            // For 3.0+ Devices (Start)
            // onActivityResult attached before constructor
            protected void openFileChooser(ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
            }

            // For Lollipop 5.0+ Devices
            public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView mWebView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
                if (uploadMessage != null) {
                    uploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
                    uploadMessage = null;
                }
                uploadMessage = filePathCallback;
                Intent intent = null;
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    intent = fileChooserParams.createIntent();
                }
                try {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SELECT_FILE);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    uploadMessage = null;
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }

            //For Android 4.1 only
            protected void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "File Browser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
            }

            protected void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
            }

        });
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.objectscounter">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ObjectsCounter"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Java код был найден в интернете и суть его работы понимаю лишь в общих чертах (в жизни с Java не работал).

Буду признателен если подскажете что и как использовать для реализации данной задачи или как это можно сделать проще. Фактически мне нужно чтобы приложение отображало веб-интерфейс и реагировало на него, как обычный браузер, при этом без не имея каких-либо элементов управления.

Comment: По второй проблеме: уберите оба метода `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` - их стандартная реализация как раз открывает все адреса внутри `WebView`, переопределение требуется, только если вы хотите иное поведение.

Comment: @woesss , Я закомментил оба метода но все равно новая страница открывается уже в хроме, а не моем приложении. (проверяю на устройстве)

Comment: Я не заметил, что они тут вообще не к месту - это методы другого класса. Его кстати и нужно назначить для требуемого поведения: `mbrowser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());`

Comment: По первой проблеме посмотрите это решение: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45004452

Comment: @woess `setWebChromeClient` заменил на `setWebViewClient`, теперь он перестал реагировать на кнопку загрузки в принципе(

Comment: Нужно не заменить, а добавить. `WebViewClient` отвечает за одно, `WebChromeClient` за другое. Друг друга они не заменяют и не взамоисключают. То есть назначить вам нужно оба.

Comment: @woesss такссс, по второй проблеме как раз помогло решение stackoverflow.com/a/45004452 :D, а вот первую оно не решило :,(

Comment: Вот класс-помощник выгрузки из стокового браузера:  [`UploadHandler.java`](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_packages_apps_browser/blob/master/src/com/android/browser/UploadHandler.java) - можете попытаться применить код из него.